# Why Tabbar that I create from MDCTabBarView() is not appear?

Tags: ios, swift, tabs, uitabbar

I try to custom tabbar by using meterial from link:
https://material.io/components/tabs/ios#using-tabs

I do follow example instruction in this link but tabbar is not appear.

This picture is tabbar that I want
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x3CS.png)

This is my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let tabBarView = MDCTabBarView()
    tabBarView.items = [
      UITabBarItem(title: "Recents", image: UIImage(named: "phone"), tag: 0),
      UITabBarItem(title: "Favorites", image: UIImage(named: "heart"), tag: 0),
    ]
    tabBarView.preferredLayoutStyle = .scrollable // or .fixed
    view.addSubview(tabBarView)
    // Configure constraints

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

My result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y47wn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give it a frame or set constraints

```
tabBarView.frame = CGRext(x:0,y:200,320,50)
view.addSubview(tabBarView)
```